# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'amazon_sales_order' doesn't exist

Tags: checkout, magento-2.2.5, amazon-payment

I'm using Magento 2.2.5 Cloud commerce version and at success page I'm getting following error

> 2019-07-01T13:35:09+00:00 INFO (6): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1146 Table 'm2.amazon_sales_order' doesn't exist,
>   query was: SELECT `main_table`.*,
>   `extension_attribute_amazon_order_reference_id`.`amazon_order_reference_id`
>   AS
>   `extension_attribute_amazon_order_reference_id_amazon_order_reference_id`,
>   `extension_attribute_amazon_order_reference_id`.`order_id` AS
>   `extension_attribute_amazon_order_reference_id_order_id` FROM
>   `sales_order` AS `main_table`  LEFT JOIN `amazon_sales_order` AS
>   `extension_attribute_amazon_order_reference_id` ON
>   main_table.entity_id =
>   extension_attribute_amazon_order_reference_id.order_id WHERE
>   ((`increment_id` = '14000018349'))

I've checked database and `amazon_sales_order` isn't exist.

I can't update the Amazon module version nor Magento 2.

Does any have SQL Script to create this table? or any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is query to create `amazon_sales_order`

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
    SET time_zone = "+00:00";
    CREATE TABLE `amazon_sales_order` (
      `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
      `order_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Order ID',
      `amazon_order_reference_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Amazon Order Reference ID'
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='amazon_sales_order';

    ALTER TABLE `amazon_sales_order`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
      ADD UNIQUE KEY `AMAZON_SALES_ORDER_ORDER_ID` (`order_id`);
    ALTER TABLE `amazon_sales_order`
      MODIFY `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID';
    ALTER TABLE `amazon_sales_order`
      ADD CONSTRAINT `AMAZON_SALES_ORDER_ORDER_ID_SALES_ORDER_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`order_id`) REFERENCES `sales_order` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Following is query to create `amazon_quote`

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";
CREATE TABLE `amazon_quote` (
  `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity ID',
  `quote_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Quote ID',
  `amazon_order_reference_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Amazon Order Reference ID',
  `sandbox_simulation_reference` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Sandbox simulation reference',
  `confirmed` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Quote confirmed with Amazon'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='amazon_quote';
ALTER TABLE `amazon_quote`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `AMAZON_QUOTE_QUOTE_ID` (`quote_id`);
ALTER TABLE `amazon_quote`
  MODIFY `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity ID';
ALTER TABLE `amazon_quote`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `AMAZON_QUOTE_QUOTE_ID_QUOTE_ENTITY_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`quote_id`) REFERENCES `quote` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```